# is possible to have a Variable Class object declaration

Tags: xcode, class, uitableview, declaration

this is my example:

```
UITableView *cell = [[MyCustomClass alloc] init];
```

Is there a way to do it someway that I can vary the class "MyCustomClass", like having a method like this:

```
-(NSObject*)newMethod:(int)intNumber{
 classVariable = someClass depending on intNumber
 UITableView *cell [[<<<classVariable>>> alloc] init];
 return cell;
}
```

I want this method so I can create correct custom cells, and to use it as a global method in my next implementations, this is the code that I use that I found in other question here in Stack Overflow (used to load custom cells from xibs):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:stringIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
    for (id currentObject in nib) {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
            cell = (MyClassCell*) currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }
    cell = (MyClassCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

My goal is to have a method which I send all the info the code above needs, which is tableViw, stringidentifier, nibName and MyClassCell <-- being this the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Class` of a class using `class`:

```
Class myclass = [MYClass class];
```

You can now pass around `myclass` as a variable, and you can use it in places that a `Class` is required:

```
id myinstance = [[myclass alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place class names or even classes in an NSArray and use indexing:

```
NSArray *classes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[ClassOne class], [ClassTwo class], [C
```

assThree class], Nil];

```
id instance = [[(Class)[classes objectAtIndex:anIndex] alloc] init];
```

If you wish to dynamically construct/use class info during runtime, you can use the NSClassFromString() function:

```
id anObject = [[NSClassFromString(@"FooBar") alloc] init];
```